# Setting a path for LaTeX style files

Tags: paths

This is a question that has come up many times but I do not seem to be able to get this to work using any of the suggestions that have been made so I would REALLY appreciate any help.

I am trying to get LaTeX to find my style files in Windows 7. I am using TeXMaker.

I create a new folder, for example C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\Macros 
This then satisfies the TDS compliant directory requirements.

I go into MikTeX settings -> Roots and add this folder. 
I then click Refresh FNDB in the General settings.

However, when I try to compile I still receive the error that the cls files cannot be found. It seems that this procedure has worked for many other people but I just cannot find what I could be doing wrong here.

Comment: What did you add as root folder? `C:\localtexmf` or `C:\localtexmf`\tex\latex\Macros`? If you used the last one, LaTeX will try to find your .sty file in `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\Macros\tex\latex\…`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Hi Bernard,
Thanks so much for your comment. This has indeed solved the problem - I was setting the root directory to contain the extra information \tex\latex\Macros as well, which all the other posts seemed to be suggesting I needed to do. This has been immensely helpful - thank you so much.